# Change the OS boot sequence?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

I've been installed the Ubuntu 14.04 in partition of hard drive other than C: drive like E: or F: drive first, then after few days later i installed the windows 7 in C:drive. After windows installation boot option or boot sequence of Ubuntu OS has gone and now windows 7 is automatically boot first and run as default and never seen the Ubuntu option now. Ubuntu Drive is also not shown in windows 7????
Kindly suggest me the solution of this problem, i want to change it and make the Ubuntu as default or run as first in my boot sequence.

Comment: Installing Windows after Ubuntu will generally cause Windows to wipe the Ubuntu install unless you are careful. So it may not exist. If you install Ubuntu afterwards on another partition, then you could dual-boot. However, you still will not be able to see Ubuntu's files within Windows, as Windows can't read Linux file systems (but Ubuntu can see Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Use Ubuntu Boot Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Use unetbootin (http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create bootable usb disc with the boot-repair iso file. Boot into usb and click 'automatic repair'